# the background image in div wont load until you refresh it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everytime I run the project. The page wont load the background image until you refresh the page 2-3 times or hit the f12 key of the browser. I'm using a preload.js also.

```
   <div class="fill-screen" style="background-image:url(../images/office.jpg); " data-src="images/office.jpg">
```

the script:

```
$(function () {
var $this, src;

    $('img').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        src = $this.data('src');
        $this.attr('src', src);
    });

    $('div').preload(function(){
        $(this).show();
        });

        });
```

and this is the css.

```
.fill-screen{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-color:greenyellow;
}
```

I want to know where did I go wrong. I just want when I run it the page will load everything.

Comment: You do not have any `<img />` in your code

Comment: You include preload script after jQuery?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, but after a number of refresh or hit f12 the background image is shown now. if i have a mistake here the background image must not show totally.

Comment: @lgabster Yes i have.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any img elements in the code you shared however you are using a background img for your div.

You are not setting src value in order to update the image in your example you need to be overriding the css for background-image with a url.

Try something like this.

```
$('.fill-screen').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var src = $this.data('src');
    $this.css('background-image', 'url(' + src +')');
});
```

Comment: Its still not working. I have to refresh the page 2-3 times or hit f12.  What could possibly be wrong on my code.